# Correct way to set time of day to TimeSpan.MaxValue in C#

Tags: c#, date

Is the following code correct?

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public bool DoPost(CommunityNewsPost post)
{
    MembershipHelper.ThrowUnlessAtLeast(RoleName.Administrator);

    DateTime? start;
    DateTime? end;

    Utility.TryParse(post.PublishStart, out start);
    Utility.TryParse(post.PublishEnd, out end);

    if (start != null)
        start -= start.Value.TimeOfDay - TimeSpan.MinValue;

    if(end!=null)
        end += TimeSpan.MaxValue - end.Value.TimeOfDay;

    return CommunityNews.Post(post.Title, post.Markdown, post.CategoryId, start, end);
}
```

And `Utility.TryParse`:

```
public static bool TryParse(string s, out DateTime? result)
{
    DateTime d;
    var success = DateTime.TryParse(s, out d);
    if (success)
        result = d;
    else
        result = default(DateTime?);

    return success;
}
```

I want `start` to be something like `09/11/2011 00:00` and `end` to be something like `09/11/2011 23:59`

Comment: You don't use the return value of `Utility.TryParse()` and it's contained in `result`. I think you should make it return `result`.

Comment: I don't use it *this time*, I **might** use it in the future. And besides, that's the pattern every `TryParse` method follows.

Comment: That's the pattern every `TryParse()` follows *because it doesn't return nullable values*. You need some way to represent failure. `TryParse` uses the return value of `false`, you can use `null`.

Comment: You are right I should rename this to just `Parse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, TimeSpan.Min/MaxValue are very large values.  Not that sure what you really want to do but the example you gave is generated by:

```
        if (start != null) start = start.Value.Date;
        if (end != null) end = start.Value.Date.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1);
```

Answer (score 3):

`TimeSpan` isn't primarily intended to represent a time of day, but to represent any time interval, even if it's several days, months or even years.

Because of this `TimeSpan.MaxValue` is approximately 20 000 years, and your code throws an exception.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things...

`DateTime.TryParse` will automatically initialize the `out` param to a default value. There is probably no reason for `Utility.TryParse` to exist.

Second, take a look at [DateTime.Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx), which is probably what you are trying to replicate.

Edit: I overlooked the Nullable type. You could refactor to something like this:

```
public bool DoPost( CommunityNewsPost post )
{
    MembershipHelper.ThrowUnlessAtLeast( RoleName.Administrator );

    DateTime value;
    DateTime? start;
    DateTime? end;

    DateTime.TryParse( post.PublishStart, out value );
    start = ( value != DateTime.MinValue ) ? new DateTime?(value.Date) : null;
    DateTime.TryParse( post.PublishEnd, out value );
    end = ( value != DateTime.MinValue ) ? 
         new DateTime?(value.Date.AddMinutes(-1.0 )) : null;

    return CommunityNews.Post(post.Title, post.Markdown, post.CategoryId, 
         start, end);
}
```

Comment: `DateTime` isn't convertible to `DateTime?` (and I don't want to declare a `DateTime` in my methods each time I parse to `DateTime?`) that's the reason for my method. Definitely I wanted DateTime.Date, thanks!

Comment: Also, `TimeSpan` can exceed one day. `TimeSpan.MaxValue` is something like [10 million days](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.maxvalue.aspx). Note also that the latest point in the day representable in .NET is 23:59.9999999 which ConmunityPost may very well round to the next day

Comment: @Nico Yeah, I went too fast. I edited the answer for Nullable types.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Paul Walls' answer, I went with this:

```
if (start != null)
    start = start.Value.Date;

if (end != null)
    end = end.Value.Date + new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59);
```